# How to list "new" member of an JavaScript object that is not instance/static member from its base or inherited class?

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, member

I'm not sure how to define this `new member` thing, please check demo below, what I want is `ListNewMemberNames`:

The code (demo.html) is assuming running in a browser

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Var1 Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        var1 = {value:7}  /* same as window.var1 = {value:7}*/

        ListMemberNames(window) 
        /* returns: ["__defineGetter__", ... "addEventListener", "alert", ... "var1"] */

        ListNewMemberNames(window)
        /* returns: ["var1"] */
        
        function ListMemberNames(obj){ /* tricks with .hasOwnProperty() or something*/ }
        function ListNewMemberNames(obj){ /* ? */ }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you mean to call `ListMemberNames(window)` *before* creating the global variable `var1` and to call `ListNewMemberNames(window)` after it, so they have something to compare (and filter for "new" members)?

Comment: @Bergi No. Execution order doesn't matter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, you can't analyze the current (or outer) lexical environment (the mapping of variable names to their values) dynamically in JavaScript. This is only possible on the top level due to the fact that top-level variables declared with `var` (or with nothing at all) get assigned to the window - check the properties that exist on the window at the beginning of pageload, put it into an array, then look at the properties that exist on it later, and find the difference.

```js
// always run this first
const properties = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(window);

// then your code does something
var1 = {value:7}

// and it is detectable by doing:
const newPropertiesOnWindow = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(window)
  .filter(prop => !properties.includes(prop));
console.log(newPropertiesOnWindow);
```

It's possible to do, barely - but I can't think of any good reason to want to do so.

Comment: Thanks, since I'm writting GM script for an existing web page, I think that means `impossible` for me :(

Comment: No, it's not impossible. All you need to do is to make sure your script runs first, before anything else. Use `@run-at document-start` in your metadata block, then retrieve the properties on the global object immediately.